# Microsoft teams app spinner has incorrect positioning in task modules - stuck to the buttom

Tags: html, css, microsoft-teams

Everything is happening in web version of Microsoft teams

EDIT 1: the content of what I'm trying to render in the task module is structured according to the docs. Manifest property `showLoadingIndicator` is set to `true`. The app calls `app.initialize()` and then, depending on situation, `app.notifySuccess()` or `app.notifyFailure(...)`

EDIT 2: This problem started 2 or 3 weeks ago. Before it was working fine.

I create a task module by sending a TaskInfo object on task/fetch request

```js
 task: {
   type,
   value: {
    title,
    height, // default 'medium'
    width, // default 'medium'
    url
   },
 },
```

I configured my microsoft teams app to use a native spinner untill my code calls `notifySuccess` function

Before the iframe is loaded I expect the spinner to be centered relative to the task module but spinner's parent containers have css rules messing up the whole alignment.

The html structure of spinner's containers is

```html
<div class="embedded-page-busy-container" ng-if="ctrl.showLoadingIndicator">
    <busy-animation class="loading-spinner" size="medium"><div class="ts-spinner-internal size-2x">
        <div class="ts-spinner-container">
            <svg class="spinner-animate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 4880">
              ...
            </svg>
        </div>
    </busy-animation>
</div>
```

The top-most div positions itself with top offset of 50%

```css
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -1.6rem 0 0 -1.6rem;
```

But the next container `busy-animation` sets the spinner in the middle of the parent container

```css
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 2rem);
    left: calc(50% - 2rem);
    z-index: 1;
```

This combination makes it so the parent container is offest vertically by 50%, but the spinner is still in the middle resulting in the spinner sitting right at the botton of the task module.

Has anyone had this problem before or maybe there's a way to pass custom css to task module to override this behaviour?

For the sake of clarity attaching a screenshot of the spinner positioning in action.
Feel free to ask for more information and/or screenshots

Thanks in advance

[Spinner positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycIct.png)

Comment: If you selectshowLoadingIndicator as true in your app manifest, to load the page correctly, modify the content pages of your tabs and task modules as described in Show a native loading indicator document.
Could you please try it once-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2#show-a-native-loading-indicator

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT
Went through the linked part and task module's content is already like that. I do call app.initialize() and when I load everything that I need I call app.notifySuccess()
The thing is, everything was working fine up unitll maybe 2-3 weeks from now

Comment: @Nazlobudnya-Have you updated the teams version? Could please check with the latest version.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Sorry I didn't quite get this. If you are talking about TeamsJS sdk then I did an update around 10 or so days ago. 
If it's about the actual Teams desktop, then I'm experiencing this issue with web version.